# Fixing Windows install by connecting its hard drive via USB to a different laptop

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, uninstall, sp3

I tried to upgrade a laptop to SP3, which broke it.  I later found out SP3 doesn't work on that 2002 laptop.  I can't uninstall SP3, or fix SP2, because the hard drive is now not detected during setup (I've read that's the problem you get).  I put the hard drive in a USB drive case and plugged it into my other laptop, and I can read (& write to) the disk okay.  (The hard drive won't fit in my other laptop, so I'm using USB.)  I need to get that disk back to SP2, or fix whatever files got screwed up causing the disk to not be recognized.  I don't want to do a re-install as there are 80GB of files on it I need, and they won't fit on the HD of my other laptop, and also because I no longer have some of the install CDs for software on it.  What do I need to do to fix that drive from my other laptop? (I don't want my working laptop (XP SP3) to get screwed with by putting an SP2 disk in the CD drive, or the non-o/s data on the other hard drive screwed with.)

Comment: i don't think you can... i think you'll need to buy/borrow another external drive to backup the important files, then reinstall windows xp on the "dead" laptop, then upgrade it to sp2 and make sure it doesn't update further.  but maybe someone else has a better solution for you.

Comment: Even if I backed it up, the "dead" laptop doesn't recognize the hard drive is there now - some files need fixed (that's in the post).

Comment: @jason: depends on what you mean by "doesn't recognize".  if the BIOS can recognize the drive but the system can't boot, windows can install from CD (reformat for instant problem-files-go-away).  if the BIOS can't recognize the drive at all, "some files" aren't the problem.

Comment: You'd think - but to repeat, BIOS sees it, but after the Windows install CD runs through a bunch of stuff, it finally says there's no hard drive, so it can't continue.

Comment: Please see me last comment after the answer below (it's long).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend putting the drive back in the original laptop and installing XP (with slipstreamed SP2 if possible) over top of the existing installation, without formatting.  This should get the OS working again, and theoretically will retain your applications and application settings.  Though I'd still recommend backing up important data - just to be on the safe side.

Comment: The computer doesn't recognize the drive is there now - so I can't do that. (In the post.)

Comment: If the laptop doesn't even SEE the drive, then it's not an OS issue.  If it's just the Windows SP3 Setup that doesn't see it you can boot using an XP Install CD and install over top of the existing (botched) installation.

Comment: The laptop (BIOS) sees the drive. Windows doesn't. I've read in multiple places this happens with this computer ->SP3 - apparently some file is modified causing Windows to think the drive is something else.  I want to focus on getting the boot record rebuilt, and SP2 repaired - from another computer.

Comment: Right. So put the old drive back in the old computer, and boot up using a Windows XP Install CD.  If the CD does not include SP3 it will see the drive and let you install Windows over top of your existing installation, without formatting anything.  This should fix your boot problem and repair Windows in the process.  Then you'll just need to install SP2.

Comment: How many times do I need to say the Windows install disk does not detect the hard disk?  Again, "I want to focus on getting the boot record rebuilt, and SP2 repaired - from another computer."

Comment: I don't think you ever said the Windows *install* disk doesn't detect the hard drive. But if that's the case, it seems that your problem is related to drivers. The Windows install CD doesn't care if your MBR is present or not. In fact, it's got a command-line mode to help repair issues like this. Have you tried booting using Knoppix or something similar? I'm curious to know if your drive is visible under a different environment on the same computer. Also, Knoppix likely has tools for fixing the MBR if that's really the issue.

Comment: Also see the answer here (http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/215902.html) on fixing your MBR using the recovery tools - you might be able to run these off of the installation CD from another computer. Once you have access, you need to run FIXMBR \device\harddisk2 (or whatever number the hdd that you're trying to fix is).

Comment: I didn't mention that I can't use the Recovery Console because I don't know the password.  I searched Google but didn't see a way around that.

Comment: @jason: if the windows *install* disc can't see the hard-drive, you need to make your own install disc with your motherboard's IDE/SATA controller drivers slipstreamed in.  use the nLite tool or similar for that.

Comment: I still have the disk I originally used to install XP on the laptop.  When I put it in, the install runs for a while, then says there's no hard disk, so it can't continue.  BIOS sees the hard disk, and I can read/write to it when it's hooked up externally (USB) to my other laptop.

Comment: Could you provide the laptop model and the links that you referred to in your original post as to the SP3 issues (and any other relevant links)?  I'm still leaning towards it being driver issues - seems like XP needs a specific mass storage device driver that isn't included in the vanilla installation.  When you say "install runs for awhile"... where does it crap out?  What's the message on the screen?  Connecting it externally via USB introduces a new set of drivers, so it's relatively unrelated to the issue at hand.

Comment: Seems like...  I still have the same original disk I origally used with no problem.  No driver "dissapeared" from it.  I wish I could get some replies about what I need to do - fix the disk from another computer.

Comment: Jason - it seems from your description like the issue is unrelated to the boot record on the drive.  If you just want to fix the boot record, boot up in your other computer using a Knoppix DVD and fix it using tools included there. Or boot up on your other computer using DOS diskettes and type 'fdisk /mbr'.  However I don't believe that this will resolve your issue.  You might even be able to put this disk in as the primary HDD in your other computer and reinstall XP on it. Though I wouldn't count on this booting in the first computer (but it might).

Comment: You can try any of these things... but you only have one set of data and no backup - and honestly, I don't think any of these options will resolve your issue.  Perhaps there's a vital piece of information I'm missing.  Could you provide your laptop model and any links to SP3 issues that you were referring to in your original post?  I _really_ want to help you resolve this issue :)

(sorry for 2 comment posts - character limit)

Comment: I made a book disk that let me remove the Recovery Console (RC) password.  I booted with an SP1 disk, entered RC, and did a fixboot c:.  Now when I bootup with the Windows install disk I don't get the disk read error after several minutes.  I tried to do an install with an SP1 disk (I only have SP2 as a non-boot package.)  I get an error "the signature for windows xp professional upgrade is invalid" error code 800b0100. I rebooted to Safe Mode, and I get an error "Safe Mode can't run under Windows Setup." Ideas?

Comment: Try the following page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307153
"To resolve this problem, rename the %WinDir%\System32\Catroot2 folder"

Comment: When I get to the point where repair should be an option, it is not. [... 3.Do not choose the option to press R to use the Recovery Console. 4.In the Windows XP Licensing Agreement, press F8 to agree to the license agreement.5.Make sure that your current installation of Windows XP is selected in the box, and then press R to repair Windows XP.] Pressing R does nothing, and the only option available is to format, with the associated warning messages.

Comment: 2 Options - 1) move the drive back to the USB housing and rename the directory using your other computer, or 2) grab a Knoppix DVD and boot using that - it'll give you filesystem access and let you do whatever you need to without shuffling hardware around. Then try the installation again.

Comment: I didn't need to do the rename you suggested.  I booted a couple more times, and tried to get in Safe Mode again, and the next time I booted the Windows install proceeded as normal.  I didn't delete/rename anything or modify the registry.

Comment: To clarify my above comment, I still wasn't getting the repair option at that point.  I've since followed a procedure to restore a backup of the registry, and now I see the repair option, and the repair install is proceeding, it copied files and rebooted, but on reboot it said "Setup will complete in aproximately 39 minutes" - I don't think that's right, and it's doing a new install - which means everything (applications, my doc directory) may be gone. Uhg.

Comment: It says setup is creating Start Menu items. Ugh. I NEVER said new/clean install.

Comment: Booted up.  Asked if I wanted to register Windows online. All my icons are there, and the old desktop documents. Good.  All the applications I tried from the Start Menu work (tested a few), except Corel Photopaint - I get registry entry not found errors.  Windows ran for a while, then froze. The mouse and keyboard don't work. Pressing the power button got Windows to shut down.  I probably need to put SP2 on it, and then all the updates for my laptop for XP Pro SP2 (drivers), there's a bunch.  The mouse and keyboard quit working again. That wasn't a problem when I first set up this laptop.

Comment: I've ran 4 times now since the "repair." Two mouse/keyboard hangs by pressing ctrl-c (to copy text from a notepad document), and two by selecting Start-Run (wasn't able to type anything in the box).

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to make sure you have all the latest drivers and SP2 installed.  Though obviously this will be difficult if you're experiencing intermittent hangs.  Maybe try using external mouse/keyboard to see if it resolves the issue until you get all the drivers updated.